# How to set box-shadow effect with hover effect in image?

Tags: css

```
$count = $result->rowCount();
echo '<div class="container">';
while($count>0)
{


    echo '<div class="row">';
    $i=0;
    while($i<3)
    {
      $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        echo '<div class="card mt-4">';
        echo '<div class="card-body" style="width:350px;height:350px"><a href="auctionDetails.php?id=';
        echo $row['code'];
        echo '"><img src="../';
        echo $row['imageurl'];
        echo '" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:100%" alt="Image">';
        echo '</a></div><div class="card-footer">';
        echo mb_strimwidth($row['name'],0,28,"...");
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark pull-right" id="likebutton" vale="'.$row['code'].'"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i></button></div></div></div>';
        $i++;
        $count--;
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

I want to set box-shadow with hover effect in the image.
`box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);` [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow5)

Without external css answer will be appreciated.

Comment: so what is the problem ? you have the box-shadow, add it on hover

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add *pseudo classes* inside HTML tags, but you can add them in the same file in the `<style>...</style>` tag.

Like so:

```
<head>
  <style>
    img:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have other images on the same page where you dont want the effect ,create class and add wherever you want effect

add "shadow" named class to your image

```
 class="img-responsive shadow"
```

and then style

```
<style type="text/css">
.shadow:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0,   0.19);
}
</style>
```